# Sharing images to Whatsapp using UIDocumentIntractionController in ios

Tags: ios, image, sharing, whatsapp

Is it possible to share Image and Text from an iOS app to **WhatsApp** using UIDocumentIntractionController or API in iPhone application development?

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20417047/whatsapp-image-sharing-ios

Answer (score 4):

Please look at this link from the FAQ:

http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013

Comment: Thanks @Sunil Targe this is what i needed. Is there any sample example for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that If your application creates photos, videos or audio notes and you’d like your users to share these media using WhatsApp, you can use the Document Interaction API to send your media to your WhatsApp contacts and groups.

You can refer this link : http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013

Answer (score -1):

In Swift 3 use this code

```
 @IBAction func whatsappShareWithImages(_ sender: AnyObject)
    {

        let urlWhats = "whatsapp://app"
        if let urlString = urlWhats.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed) {
            if let whatsappURL = URL(string: urlString) {

                if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL as URL) {

                    if let image = UIImage(named: "whatsappIcon") {
                        if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) {
                            let tempFile = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("Documents/whatsAppTmp.wai")
                            do {
                                try imageData.write(to: tempFile, options: .atomic)
                                self.documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: tempFile)
                                self.documentInteractionController.uti = "net.whatsapp.image"
                                self.documentInteractionController.presentOpenInMenu(from: CGRect.zero, in: self.view, animated: true)

                            } catch {
                                print(error)
                            }
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    // Cannot open whatsapp
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Add this code in your app "plist"

```
  <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>whatsapp</string>
    </array>
```

You can also refer to small app for reference : https://github.com/nithinbemitk/iOS-Whatsapp-Share