# iOS sharing document to WhatsApp using UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, swift, share, whatsapp, uidocumentinteraction

I'm trying to share a simple .txt file to WhatsApp using UIDocumentInteractionController on iOS.

I found [this FAQ of WhatsApp](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/iphone/23559013/) explaining the Custom URL Scheme for WhatsApp, but it is not explaining how to share another document to WhatsApp. This should be possible with a WhatsApp update released about 2 months ago.

I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40298818/4543961), but it does not work for other document types. Can anyone help me?

My code, that does not work, because the URL Scheme is wrong:

```
let urlWhats = "whatsapp://app"
            if let urlString = urlWhats.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed) {
if let whatsappURL = URL(string: urlString) {
                    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL) {

  activityVc = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: txtPath))
  activityVc.uti = "net.whatsapp.document"
  activityVc.presentOptionsMenu(from: CGRect.zero, in: self.view, animated: true)
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried and narrow down the explanation of what isn't working. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I added my code. Maybe this can help someone...

Comment: Are you sure it's possible? The page you link to mentions some `net.whatsapp.*` schemes but not `net.whatsapp.document`.

Comment: Yes I am, because whatsapp posted in their change log, that you can now share any kind of document. On Android it is working ;)